# C# connecting to mysql instead sqlserver

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In our company intranet we have sqlserver running, with database(s). There is PC app, written in. NET, connecting to database(s), for accounting purposes, stock management, etc.. 
If we would convert and migrate DB to run on Mysql, how complex would be to rewrite this existing app in manner that we keep all funcionality? Is writing from scratch only option, or we could achive results with minor interventions in EntityFramework domain?

Tnx

Comment: are you already using `Entity Framework` as `ORM` tool ? if `yes` then version of `Entity framework` ?

Comment: It is a 3rd party app, so I am not aware of EF version.

Comment: which way you're going to migrate the data ? I mean data migration approach ? code first or what ?

Comment: Exactly that are the recomendations I am searching for..

Comment: are you using `code first` ?

Comment: Well, I am not the one who is going to do the actual work, I am in the process of collecting informations how complex in the terms of time consuming would be the given scenario, so I could ask the app providing company to do the code rewriting and DB migrating, or to dismantle the whole idea.

Comment: we can give you a support if you provide the answers for the above questions. otherwise how can we help to you ?

Comment: I was hoping for answer like: It is better to write it from scratch, or :there is no need to write it from scratch, only minor part of code needs rewriting, or something like that.